# How to make this keep running when tab is not active?

Tags: php, javascript, timer

```
function timer(time,max) {
   if(time-1>=0) {
     --time;
       $("#timer2").html(Math.ceil(time/100));
          pix = Math.round((time/max)*100);
   document.getElementById('timer').style.width = pix+"%";
  setTimeout("timer("+time+","+max+")",10);
  }
 }
```

That's the Javascript.

```
 You have <font style='color: #ff0' id='timer2'><?PHP echo $time; ?></font> seconds left until you can skill again<br>
<div style='background-color: black; width: 100px;'>
    <div style='background-color: #ffd700; text-align: center; width: 100%' id='timer'>&nbsp;
    </div>
</div>
<script>
    timer(<?PHP echo $time*100; ?>,<?PHP echo $time*100; ?>);
</script>
```

Basically, the time can be X seconds. The timer runs every 10 milliseconds so the bar is smooth looking. The problem is, when you are out of that tab, it stops moving. Is there a way to cure this code to do this?

Thanks!

Comment: Which browser? Google chrome has limit for one call per second when tab is inactive.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using jQuery already, check out [jQuery timer](http://code.google.com/p/jquery-timer/) plugin.

Answer (score 1):

In modern browsers, timeouts and intervals are throttled when the tab is inactive, so your timer function is only firing once per second instead of 100 times per second while the tab is inactive.

To work around this, you need to store the time when the animation starts (`Date.now()`), 
then whenever your timer function fires, you'll check the current time, figure out how much time has passed since the animation started, then animate your element based on the amount of time that has elapsed since it started.

Example ([jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Gz3Hb/2/))

```
timer = function(max) {
    if (timer.start === undefined) timer.start = Date.now();
    if (timer.max === undefined) timer.max = max;

    var max = timer.max,
        elapsed = Date.now() - timer.start,
        left = Math.max(max - elapsed, 0),
        pctLeft = Math.min(left/max, 1);

    $('#timer2').html(Math.ceil(left/1000));
    $('#timer').css('width', pctLeft * 100 + '%');

    if (left > 0) setTimeout(timer, 30);
    else timer.start = timer.max = undefined;
 }

timer(5000);
​
```